# Why is window.location.search empty?

Tags: javascript

If I `console.log(window.location)` I get this:

```
Location {replace: function, assign: function, ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "https://localhost:3000", hash: "#/account/content?hello=world"…}
ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList
assign: function () { [native code] }
hash: "#/account/content?hello=world"
host: "localhost:3000"
hostname: "localhost"
href: "https://localhost:3000/#/account/content?hello=world'"
origin: "https://localhost:3000"
pathname: "/"
port: "3000"
protocol: "https:"
reload: function reload() { [native code] }
replace: function () { [native code] }
search: ""
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
__proto__: Location
```

I expect `search` to be `?hello=world`, but it isn't.

Why?

I'm using Chrome 35

Comment: Everything after the `#` (including the `#`) is part of `window.location.hash`.

Comment: Best practice is to append the named anchor at the end, see this answer: https://superuser.com/a/498625/12170

Comment: I have the same issue with a React app. My company app has this hash in the url, some strange React format.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Because `?hello=world` isn't considered the query string in your case.
It's part of the `anchor` (`#`) which can be obtained using

```
window.location.hash
```