# Under what conditions would window.location.search be undefined?

Tags: javascript, window.location

We inconsistently see this error in our logs:

> Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

It occurs on this line of code: `var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1)`

Unfortunately, the error is not consistently reproduced, but the flow is:

1. Open new window via JavaScript.
2. In new window, invoke this line of code.

Based on Googling, internal testing, and answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789587/why-is-window-location-search-empty/23789612), it seems like `window.location.search` should at worse be an empty string, but never undefined. If `window` or `location` were undefined, then it would be expected for the error to appear differently.

Under what conditions could `window.location.search` be undefined?

Comment: Did you check what the browser of the user is ? It might be a browser for which the API is not correctly implemented

Comment: @Axnyff thanks for the reply. it happens on chrome, but not consistently unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe your website is being scraped by some bot that uses jsdom, for example. Or some other browser like PhantomJS. Basically, any browser/library that doesn't implement `window.location.search`. I think `jsdom` is the most probable one.

Comment: *it happens on chrome* how do you know this? This sounds like a bot to me

Comment: Right, you can't tell the real browser by reported user-agent. You have to test its features and fingerprint, and even then you can be fooled :)

Comment: @Liam you're right. it's reported as chrome in sentry, but perhaps it's a bot? any suggestions for validating this? thanks for the help!

Comment: Like I say in my answer, not your problem. you're doing the right thing. You're right it should be an empty string. If it's not, then that's the clients fault. Just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All browsers should (and all the usul suspects do) implement the [w3c guidelines](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/history.html#dom-location-search) for this property. These state:

> The search attribute's getter must run these steps:
>
> 1. If this Location object's relevant Document is non-null and its
>    origin is not same origin-domain with the entry settings object's
>    origin, then throw a "SecurityError" DOMException.
> 2. If this Location object's url's query is either null or the empty
>    string, return the empty string.
> 3. Return "?", followed by this Location object's url's query.

So this property should either throw a `SecurityError` or be an empty string. If your not seeing this then it's a browser with a bug or a browser that does not implement this specification correctly (possibly a web crawler).

Either way providing your abiding by the w3c guideless. **I'd say this isn't your problem**. Your job is to write code that abides by the specifications of the w3c, it's the browsers job to stick to these. If they don't, all bets are off. Any number of things could break.

---

You do state:

> it happens on chrome

But I'd question the validity of this. It's very hard to actually identify a browser and it's trivial to spoof a browsers `user-agent`.
[Kudos to Maxim's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64092826/under-what-conditions-would-window-location-search-be-undefined/64098256#comment113347002_64092826)